# Как хранить адреса и имена в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Мне необходимо хранить в БД адреса и контактные данные людей (телефон, email, ФИО, паспортные данные). Я не очень силен в теории РСУБД, но хочу все сделать красиво. Я неплохо знаю SQL, в принципе для меня нет проблем сделать JOIN на 3 таблицы. Вот какие вопросы передо мной встали и варианты реализации:

**1. Имена**

Имена будут использоваться в основном для поиска по фамилии либо по ФИО (никому же в голову не придет искать по имени-отчеству). Соответственно, первый вопрос:

1.1) Имеет ли смысл хранить имя в виде 2 колонок (фамилия + имя-отчество) или просто хранить одной колонкой?

1.2) Насколько хорошо работает полнотекстовый поиск по именам?

1.3) Умеет ли MySQL находить по частичным совпадениям (Ковалев ~== Коваленко) или при неправильном нажатии клавиш (Пертов -> Петров)?

**2. Адрес**

Адрес, в отличие от имени, надо вынести в отдельную таблицу. Первый вопрос есть ли смысл в этом (я понимаю, что нормализация - это гуд), если максимальное количество записей будет около 10 000? Какой выигрыш это даст, если любой запрос с JOIN'ом всегда медленнее чем, без него? Меняться адрес будет очень редко, мне кажется, что можно не выносить в отдельную таблицу. Насчет вертикальной дупликации - у меня как минимум по именам будет дупликация: 2000 Андреев, 2000 Александров же никого не смущают, а что плохого в том, чтобы 2000 Москв иметь?

Т.е. по идее я понимаю, что по логике надо сделать в таблице person поле fk_address_id -> таблицу address:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |     city     |             street          |   house    |    apt  |
+------+--------------+-----------------------------+------------+---------+
```

По идее можно дальше пойти, вынести например города и улицы им принадлежащие, в отдельные таблицы, но не вижу смысла это делать.

Может есть какие-то устоявшиеся правила, лучшие практики, как это принято делать? Направьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: 1.1 - хранить одной, поиск по шаблону(частичное совпадение, `%Петров%`) никто не отменял. 1.2 1.3 - плохо(тяжелые запросы выходят) 2.ххх Подумайте заранее о подключении нормализованой базы адресов, например КЛАДР

Comment: КЛАДР - штука могучая, но здесь будет избыточен. Я имею в виду, имеет ли смысл делать отдельную таблицу адресов? Или можно эти поля разместить в таблице юзер? Что мне даст такое усложнение структуры?

Comment: Читать до просветления: [Заблуждения программистов об именах](https://habr.com/en/post/146901/) (а также [примеры](https://habr.com/en/post/431866/)), [У семи программистов адрес без дома](https://habr.com/en/company/hflabs/blog/260601/)

Comment: Юмор - это очень хорошо, но к решению проблемы это меня не приблизило. А хочется каких-то грамотных советов.

Comment: Усложнение структуры даст вам в будущем возможность узнать что муж\жена\дети - делают у вас заказы(т.е. те кто проживает на одной территории). Про КЛАДР я не просто так сказал, возьмите их структуру, не тащите всю их базу(если для вас их база избыточна)

Comment: @tnsaturday это не юмор, а суровая правда жизни

Comment: @tnsaturday совет вам уже написали, взять готовую структуру для хранения адреса, например КЛАДР который всё предусмотрел за вас, и хранить ФИО в одной колонке без ограничения на длинну. если вы считаете что КЛАДР слишком избыточен и сложен - возьмите ФИАС =) он проще и так же предусмативает почти все поля

Comment: Владимир, извиняюсь, не могу найти саму структуру их БД, не поделитесь ссылочкой?

Comment: @tnsaturday Ставьте собачку перед именем, чтобы получатель видел уведомление. www.ksoft.ru/opis_kladr.htm https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/КЛАДР http://www.sql.ru/forum/198919/struktura-kladra-kak-v-ndfl это так на вскидку, первые же адреса описывающие структуру хранения у них адреса... =)

Comment: кладр не точен, сейчас актуальнее база фиас

Comment: или в кладр завезли примари кей?)

Comment: Открыл вот книжку авторитетного издателя. Вот адрес хранится вместе с именем и никаких проблем.
https://i.ibb.co/gJT22Z3/dbdesign.png